# Seeking some C# RegEx help

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to create a RegEx expression that will successfully parse the following line:

```
"57" "testing123" 82 16 # 13 26 blah blah
```

What I want is to be able to do is identify the numbers in the line. Currently, what I'm using is this:

```
[0-9]+
```

which parses fine. However, where it gets tricky is if the number is in quotes, like "57" is or like "testing123" is, I do not want it to match.

In addition to that, anything after the hash sign (the '#"), I do not want to match anything at all after the hash sign.

So in this example, the matches I should be getting are "82" and "16". Nothing else should match.

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: "57" 12 "testing123" 82 16 # 13 26 blah blah  Should 12 be matched?

Comment: @blizpasta - Yes because 12 is not in quotes and its not after the hash sign.

Comment: So we don't interpret " 12 " as being in quotes because the input is assumed to always have a closing quote? Are nested quotes allowed?

Comment: @blizpasta - Right. Because there is a start quote and end quote, then the 12, then another start quote and end quote. Nested quotes are allowed if they are preceded by a backslash. for example: 15 "John said \"Hello\"" 27 should match 15 and 27

Comment: What would be the result for `This is a 12" tube with length 33 called "aluminium"`? 12 or 33 or both?

Comment: @Hyperboreus - I can almost guarantee that my input will never come in like that. BUT, for the sake of completeness, it should match both 12 and 33. However, there is probably no RegEx expression in the world that could properly parse that without some sort of artifical intelligence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be easier for you to build 3 different regexes, and then create the logic that combines them:

1. Check, whether the string has #, and ignore everything after it.
2. Check, for all the matches of "\d+", and ignore all of them
3. Check everything that's left, whether it matches [0-9]+

Comment: Igor, your answer is looking more and more like the better solution. I want to keep this question open for a day or two though, just to see what other clever answers people can come up with

Comment: Igor - I wound up going with your answer. Its just easier to do and easier to manage this way.

Answer (score 0):

.Net regular expression can rather easily parse this string. The following pattern should match everything until the comment:

```
\A      # Start of the string
(?>
    (?<Quoted>  # A quoted string
        ""          # Open quotes
        [^""\\]*            # non quotes or backslashes
        (?:\\.[^""\\]*)*    # but allow escaped characters
        ""          # Close quotes
    )
    |
    (?<Number>  # A number
        \d+         # some digits
    )
    |
    \s+          # Whitespace separator
)*
```

If you also want to match the comment, add:

```
(?<Comment>
    \# .*
)?
\z
```

You can get your numbers in a single `Match`, using all captures of the "Number" group:

```
Match parsed = Regex.Match(s, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
CaptureCollection numbers = parsed.Groups["Number"].Captures;
```

Missing from this pattern is mainly unquoted string tokens, such as `4 8 this 15that`, which can add some complexity, depending on how we'd want it to work.